# Why can I use `as` but not assign the type for mapped values in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, casting

I have a list of objects, which are declared with `as const`.

I also need a list of the same values from the objects, but don't want to maintain two lists.

And so i have this...

```
export const patternTypes = [
    { title: 'Starts with', value: 'startsWith' },
    { title: 'Contains', value: 'contains' },
    { title: 'Regular Expression', value: 'regex' },
] as const;

const patternValues = patternTypes.map(item => item.value); // typed as string[]
```

Because of where I am using the values list (a zod enum), I need to cast the type to `[string, ...string[]]`.

I want to know why I can cast the type of `patternValues` to`[string, ...string[]]` using `as` after the map, but I cannot declare the type of the variable beforehand using `const patterns: [string, ...string[]]`.

My understanding of `as` and type declaration was they are doing effectively the same thing. Both need to be compatible with the type you are casting to, hense why some solutions are `as any as <type I want>` to get around compatibility.

Can someone explain to me...

why I can do this

```
const patternValues = patternTypes.map(item => item.value) as [string, ...string[]];
```

But I cannot do this

```
const patternValues: [string, ...string[]] = patterns.map(item => item.value);
```

Comment: you just have to give map function's return type `const patternValues: String[] = patterns.map<String>(item => item.value);`, by default it is set to `any[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Type Assertions

Docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

TypeScript only allows type assertions which convert to a more specific or less specific version of a type. This rule prevents “impossible” coercions like:
[image]

```
const x = "hello" as number;
```

### Type declaration

When you declare a type for a variable, only the more specific type can be used when assigning a value.

[image]

```
const x: string = "hello" as any as string | number
```

Comment: The type of `patternTypes.map(item => item.value)` is  `("startsWith" | "contains" | "regex")[]`, so it can  convert to `[string, ...string[]]` by `as`, but cant  assign to type `[string, ...string[]]`.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't doing the same thing. `as` is more forceful and will override what the compiler knows about the type. It's a cast and can be use to insist that an object is of a particular type even though its current type disagrees.

That's not true for type declarations such as `const patterns: [string, ...string[]]`, whose values must be known at compile time to be assignable in order to be used.

Type declarations can be very handy and are usually perfectly safe, while `as` is more dangerous and should be used with more caution.

Comment: [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) should not be called *casting*. In TypeScript we cannot change a variables data type at runtime which is something you can do with a cast. All you do is *assert* a variable to have some type.

Comment: Yea that is why it's a bit confusing. Since `string[]` and `[string, ...string[]]` are effectively the same type. That destination of casting not being a thing in TS is also a solid call out. That helps my mental model a ton!

Comment: @Behemoth were runtime casting a thing in TypeScript, I would agree with you that the distinction matters. As it is I think your point adds more confusion than it removes.